# Airflow: How to load data from a REST API to BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, airflow

I am new to Airflow here, and I am trying to write a Python method to insert data into BigQuery from a REST API, but I am having no luck.

So far, I have tried to read the documentation, but I have not found an example of what I am trying to accomplish; though, I have written the following code, but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
def insert_from_api_to_bq():
    
    request1 = Request(
        '[URL GOES GERE]', headers=headers)

    sale_list = urlopen(request1).read()
    dec_sale_list = json.loads(sale_list)
    for sale in dec_sale_list['SaleList']:
        print("sale ID: " + sale['SaleID'] + " Customer:" + sale['Customer'] + " Order Date: " + sale['OrderDate'])

with DAG("sales_data_pipeline", start_date=datetime(2021, 1 ,1),
    schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    downloading_sales = PythonOperator(
        task_id="downloading_sales",
        python_callable=download_sales
```

Comment: You have to be careful with Airflow and python operator. Airflow is an orchestrator, not a data processor. Use the Mazlum code in a third party processing unit (Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, or even a container with a KubernetesPodOperator with Composer 2) but avoid to use orchestrator processing resource for data processing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the good direction.

In your `Python` method that retrieves data from the api, you can then transform and load the result to a `BigQuery` table with `Python` client :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def insert_from_api_to_bq():
    
    request1 = Request(
        '[URL GOES GERE]', headers=headers)

    sale_list = urlopen(request1).read()
    dec_sale_list = json.loads(sale_list)
    
    # you can transform and adapt dec_sale_list before writing to BQ
    client = bigquery.Client()
    client.insert_rows_json(f'{dataset}.{table}', dec_sale_list)

with DAG("sales_data_pipeline", start_date=datetime(2021, 1 ,1),
    schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    downloading_sales = PythonOperator(
        task_id="downloading_sales",
        python_callable=download_sales
```

The `insert_rows_json` method allows saving a `Python` list of `Dict` to `BigQuery`.

Comment: @johnm have you solved your issue ?

Comment: Yes, thank you - but, if it was an XML to BigQuery, is that possible?

Comment: If it’s an XML, you need to transforms your rows with Python to a list of Dict. Then you could use the insert_rows method that I used in my answer.

Comment: Ok - where can I find an example of that in a DAG?